# Wobbly bottom bracket on Radford, need guidance to replace

Tags: mountain-bike, crankset, bottom-bracket, replacement

I have an aluminium frame Raleigh bike that's been stuck at the back of my garage for a few years now. It has a wobbly bottom crank. I assume the bearings have gone, but A; I don't have the tool to get the crank out, and B; I don't even know if the crank can be replaced.

It has square things that the pedal stems attach to each side, and after I managed to force the pedal shafts off the crank, there was a thin nut (lock nut?) which I removed from the protruding thread. I don't have a picture currently, but the right side(where the thin nut was) looks like the left side of this picture;

[image]
which is a [Tredz.co.uk Raleigh crank](https://www.tredz.co.uk/.Raleigh-Bottom-Bracket-Set_52302.htm?sku=142054&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=google_shopping&gclid=EAIaIQobChMInpfpwYTp1QIVQ77tCh3zKQgiEAkYDiABEgLtHPD_BwE).

So how do I find out which crank I need and what tool I need to remove the old one? Also, do I need any extra tools to install the new one?

I'd love to get the bike working again, and the cranks seem to be pretty cheap.

### Edit:

Here are the photos:
[image]
[image]

## Update:

Thanks to you guys I could move forward with a better understanding of what I needed to do. For clarity, here are some better pics of the bike and the removed BB:
(click for original size)
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
I mistakenly thought it was a Raleigh, but that was my other bike. This one is a Radford. The new BB I bought looks a lot like the one I posted first actually.
Thanks for the help Guys.

Comment: I don't think you have what the picture shows. The picture is of a sealed cartridge bottom bracket assembly. These do not have a lock ring. What you see in the picture is what screws into the frame, and that's it; the pedal cranks go onto that, then the crank lugnuts and that's it.  If there was a lock ring, I think you have a "pressed cup and cone" style bottom bracket (only seen on either very old bikes or recently made "bicycle shaped objects").  You can replace a pressed cup and cone BB with a cartridge; removing the cup may be difficult.

Comment: The person who made this video (replacement of cup-and-cone with cartridge) found it necessary to use a special (evidently custom?) tool to grab onto the cup-and-cone bottom bracket's cup to remove it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_pE6oXMNv24

Comment: Can you include a picture of the bottom bracket so the type can be identified?

Comment: Hi @Kaz It's not one of those old types. At least I'm pretty sure it's not. I'll upload a pic in a day or two, the bike is over my dad's atm, he has way more tools than I do, so I do the work over there.

Comment: There are 4-5 different ways that BB cartridges are installed, with aluminum frames more likely to have an odd one.

Comment: Don't be confused by the comments that there's no lockring on modern types.  While technically  true, there **is** a ring that screws into the non-drive (left) side (in this [BB-UN26](http://bike.shimano.com/content/sac-bike/en/home/road/drivetrain/bottom-brackets/bb-un26.html) from Shimano it's grey plastic. But it looks different on some other models. (also @Kaz)

Comment: If you can borrow (or buy) the correct tools, you might be best off going to a bike shop with the old part, where they can be sure of supplying the right part.

Comment: @ChrisH Maybe the thin lock nut has something to do with the aluminium frame being weaker or something, or like what Daniel R Hicks said, but I'm 90% sure it looks just like the pic I posted on the non-drive side, a bit of thread sticks out and thats where the lock nut was. I'm trying to get my dad to post me a pic but I might have to wait till I go over if he can't.

Comment: @ChrisH pics added

Comment: @DanielRHicks pics added

Comment: @Kaz picks added

Comment: Regardless of the specifics, at this point you need to remove the visible cups with the appropriate bottom bracket tool.  This may be the Park BBT-22 or a different one, depending on the precise dimensions of the splines visible in your photos.  After you get one cup off you may find you have a loose ball unit, a cartridge unit similar to the one above, with cups on both ends, or a Shimano style cartridge with a cup only one end (and threads directly in the body of the other end).  But they still come apart the same, generally with the same wrench you used on the first cup.

Comment: Thanks Dan, so if it has 22 teeth, would that tool definitely fit, or are there other dimensions to consider?

Comment: 20 tooth sorry!

Comment: I think it will fit. I'm gona get it. Thanks for help.

Comment: I see! So what could this "locknut" be? Maybe just something that (in addition to the opposite thread) helps prevent movement of the BB due to precession? In any case, not all cartridge BB's have this, and in many installations there isn't any protruding tread that could take it.

Comment: @Kaz That's odd. As it was my first experience and looking at the design, I would have thought it was necessary to lock the thread in case of accidental loosening.

Comment: I'm gona try and take the bike to a shop near me now so I don't have to buy a tool I would probably only use once. They can match the cartridge for me then as well.

Comment: @n00dles bottom brackets are threaded in the correct direction so that the mechanism of precession, as the cranks are pedaled, acts to tighten rather than loosen. Maybe the locknut prevents this process from tightening the BB too much over years of use (rather than loosening), so that it's not so hard to remove?

Comment: Got it off anyway guys. Clamped the tool on wit g-clamp so it wouldn't slip off while I gave it the beans! One of the bearing casings look right messed up lol. See added pics. I got new BB too. I b riding soon. Thanks for help :-)

Comment: @all see above^ stupid there's no way to notify all commenters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have in the picture is a *cartridge-style bottom bracket* which contains the bottom bracket bearings. What you called the 'pedal stems' are the *cranks*.

Cranks should be removed from the square tapers on the bracket shaft with a special crank puller tool such as the [Park Tool CWP-7](http://www.parktool.com/product/universal-crank-puller-for-square-taper-and-splined-cranks-cwp-7). If you forced the cranks off by other means you have possibly damaged them. If re-installed on a bottom bracket they may keep working loose.

The bottom bracket is removed using a bottom bracket tool such as the [Park Tool BBT-22](http://www.parktool.com/product/bottom-bracket-tool-bbt-22) that fits into the splines in the cartridge body.

Comment: Because n00dles removed some kind of lock ring after the pedal cranks, I suspect his bike might have a cup-and-cone bottom bracket.

Comment: @Kaz, yes quite possibly

Comment: Yes, it was a nightmare getting the _cranks_ off, I hammered them while using a wood cushion, but they wouldn't budge, so in the end I levered them off as evenly as I could with a chunky old masonry chisel! I wondered what the threads were for. I'll do it properly next time. The bike is over my dad's atm, so I'll add a picture in a couple of days, maybe you could advise me further then. Thanks.

Comment: @n00dles yeah that's the wrong tool for the job.  But what's done is done, so best now is work on the bottom bracket.  When that's fixed refit the old cranks, and if they're sloppy then hunt out some replacements.

Comment: @n00dles if you have a bike cooperative in your area then they'll have the custom tools required.

Comment: @Criggie I had a quick look but I don't think so, I'm in Swansea, UK.

Comment: http://www.ben-network.org.uk/ seems to have some kind of presense in swansea and does bike stuff as part of a greater effort.  https://en-gb.facebook.com/Re-Cycle-swansea-202611056499653/ also and  finally   https://recyclesouthwales.wordpress.com/  looks relevant too.

Comment: pics added to post

Comment: Those are pretty out of focus and a little too close to tell some things, but the BBT-22 that @ArgentiApparatus mentioned should be the correct tool. Be aware that to take the BB out, you will unscrew it COUNTER clockwise on the left side of the bike and CLOCKWISE on the right side of the bike. Then you should be able to find a cartridge BB to replace it. Just make sure to get one with the same length spindle.

Comment: Ok. Yeah, my father's like sixty-odd, so I wasn't expecting a great pic! So the BB comes out the drive-side, right? I just unscrew it on that side? And same for installation?

Comment: Look for the a Park Tool YouTube video on the BBT-22 tool, or bottom bracket installation

Comment: With the crank press (misnamed "crank puller") tool, you would have been amazed at how easy it is to get a pedal off. Some of them come with an integrated wrench. Just screw the press into the pedal crank, then turn the wrench so that the tool's pin exerts pressure against the bottom bracket axle. You might have to put your weight into it during the critical unbinding moment, but that's about it.